# compare value from EditText

Tags: android

I want to compare a value from EditText the user will input it with a string I have it and it does not work at all here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText username, password;
TextView text;
String s_username = "samer";
String s_password = "12345";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    username=findViewById(R.id.editTextText_user);
    password=findViewById(R.id.editTextText_pass);
    text=findViewById(R.id.t4);

}
public void sign_in (View v)
{
    if(username.getText().toString()==s_username)
        text.setText("Correct");
    //text.setText("Correct");
}
```

every thing is working and if I reomve the // from the last row it will work but I need it to work after the if not alone

Comment: You should look at this:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/7520432/2289835

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a simple java thing actually.
Use `.equals()` functions to compare two Strings.

Example:

```
if(string1.equals(string2)){
 ----something----
} Else {
 ----Something else----
}
```